# Importing Large XML file into SQL 2.5Gb

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml

Hi I am trying to import a large XML file into a table on my sql server (2014)

I have used the code below for smaller files and thought it would be ok as this is a once off,  I kicked it off yesterday and the query was still running when I came into work today so this is obviously the wrong route.

here is the code.

```
CREATE TABLE files_index_bulk
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)


INSERT INTO files_index_bulk(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn, 2) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\scripts\icecat\files.index.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;


SELECT * FROM files_index_bulk
```

Can anyone point out another way of doing this please ive looked around at importing large files and it keeps coming back to using bulk. which I already am.

thanks in advance.

here is the table I am using I want to pull all the data into.

```
USE [ICECATtesting]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[files_index]    Script Date: 28/04/2017 20:10:44 
******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[files_index](
    [Product_ID] [int] NULL,
    [path] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Updated] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Quality] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Supplier_id] [int] NULL,
    [Prod_ID] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [Catid] [int] NULL,
    [On_Market] [int] NULL,
    [Model_Name] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Product_View] [int] NULL,
    [HighPic] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [HighPicSize] [int] NULL,
    [HighPicWidth] [int] NULL,
    [HighPicHeight] [int] NULL,
    [Date_Added] [varchar](150) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

and here is a snippit of the xml file.

```
<ICECAT-interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://data.icecat.biz/xsd/files.index.xsd">
  <files.index Generated="20170427010009">
  <file path="export/level4/EN/11.xml" Product_ID="11" Updated="20170329110432" Quality="SUPPLIER" Supplier_id="2" Prod_ID="PS300E-03YNL-DU" Catid="151" On_Market="0" Model_Name="Satellite 3000-400" Product_View="587591" HighPic="" HighPicSize="0" HighPicWidth="0" HighPicHeight="0" Date_Added="20050627000000">
  </file>
  <file path="export/level4/EN/12.xml" Product_ID="12" Updated="20170329110432" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="7" Prod_ID="91.42R01.32H" Catid="151" On_Market="0" Model_Name="TravelMate  740LF" Product_View="40042" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/12-31699.jpg" HighPicSize="19384" HighPicWidth="170" HighPicHeight="192" Date_Added="20050627000000">
  </file>
  <file path="export/level4/EN/13.xml" Product_ID="13" Updated="20170329110432" Quality="SUPPLIER" Supplier_id="2" Prod_ID="PP722E-H390W-NL" Catid="151" On_Market="0" Model_Name="Portégé 7220CT / NW2" Product_View="37021" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/13-31699.jpg" HighPicSize="27152" HighPicWidth="280" HighPicHeight="280" Date_Added="20050627000000">
  </file>
```

Comment: You could write your own program that uses a SAX parser to insert the records. It might not be much faster, but at least you could add some kind of progress meter into it, so you know it is working correctly.

Comment: I will look that up. I was hoping to keep it all within sql if possible. there must be a way of doing this gradually rather than loading it all into memory at once.

Comment: What's the point of storing 2.5GB of text data into a *single* cell? That's an entire database's worth of data.

Comment: Have you tried executing the query *without* `SINGLE_BLOB`?

Answer (score 3):

The max size of an XML column value in SQL Server is 2GB.  It will not be possible to import a 2.5GB file into a single XML column.

**UPDATE**

Since your underlying objective is to transform XML elements within the file into table rows, you don't need to stage the entire file contents into a single XML column. You can avoid the 2GB limitation, reduce memory requirements, and improve performance by shredding the XML in client code and using a bulk insert technique to insert batches of multiple rows.

The example Powershell script below uses an XmlTextReader to avoid reading the entire XML into a DOM and uses SqlBulkCopy to insert batches of many rows at once. The combination of these techniques should allow you to insert millions rows in minutes rather than hours. These same techniques can be implemented in a custom app or SSIS script task.

I noticed a couple of the table columns specify `varchar(1)` yet the XML attribute values contain many characters. You'll need to either expand length of the columns or transform the source values.

```
[String]$global:connectionString = "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";
[System.Data.DataTable]$global:dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
[System.Xml.XmlTextReader]$global:xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\FilesToImport\files.xml");
[Int32]$global:batchSize = 10000;

Function Add-FileRow() {
    $newRow = $dt.NewRow();
    $null = $dt.Rows.Add($newRow);
    $newRow["Product_ID"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_ID");
    $newRow["path"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("path");
    $newRow["Updated"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Updated");
    $newRow["Quality"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Quality");
    $newRow["Supplier_id"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Supplier_id");
    $newRow["Prod_ID"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Prod_ID");
    $newRow["Catid"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Catid");
    $newRow["On_Market"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("On_Market");
    $newRow["Model_Name"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Model_Name");
    $newRow["Product_View"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_View");
    $newRow["HighPic"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPic");
    $newRow["HighPicSize"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicSize");
    $newRow["HighPicWidth"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicWidth");
    $newRow["HighPicHeight"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicHeight");
    $newRow["Date_Added"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Date_Added");
}

try
{

    # init data table schema
    $da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.files_index WHERE 0 = 1;", $global:connectionString);
    $null = $da.Fill($global:dt);
    $bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($global:connectionString);
    $bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.files_index";

    $recordCount = 0;

    while($xmlReader.Read() -eq $true)
    {

        if(($xmlReader.NodeType -eq [System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element) -and ($xmlReader.Name -eq "file"))
        {
            Add-FileRow -xmlReader $xmlReader;
            $recordCount += 1;
            if(($recordCount % $global:batchSize) -eq 0) 
            {
                $bcp.WriteToServer($dt);
                $dt.Rows.Clear();
                Write-Host "$recordCount file elements processed so far";
            }
        }

    }

    if($dt.Rows.Count -gt 0)
    {
        $bcp.WriteToServer($dt);
    }

    $bcp.Close();
    $xmlReader.Close();

    Write-Host "$recordCount file elements imported";

}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, what command would you use to skip the importing it to a single column then getting it into a table (as that is my desired result)?

Comment: @JohnSpencer, your desired result is unclear to me. Is it that the table in your question is a staging table and your desired result in to shred each XML value into multiple rows to insert into another table? If so, your best bet would be to parse the XML in a client app or PS script (maybe an XmlReader or similar) rather than using a staging table. Maybe we can help if you provide the final table and sample XML.

Comment: Hi Dan thanks for looking, I have updated the question shown my destination table I would like the data from the xml file files.index.xml to go into [dbo].[files_index].  I have a daily file with the same structure as im new to xml I am just pulling it in to a temp table the putting the data into its own table, (same structure as above) this works fine, however as this file is so big my method does not work.

Comment: Thankyou for all that code I really appreciate it but im getting this error 
    when running the powershell file At C:\Scripts\test.ps1:64 char:53
+     Write-Host "$recordCount file elements imported ";
+                                                     ~~
    The string is missing the terminator: ".
    At C:\Scripts\test.ps1:70 char:3
+ })
+   ~ Missing closing ')' in expression.
    + CategoryInfo  : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

Comment: @JohnSpencer, I copy/pasted the code into a Powershell ISE window, changed the connection string, and it ran successfully. There are 68 lines in the script but I see line 70 referenced in the error message. Could there be some extraneous lines in your version?

Comment: Dan thanks I worked it out thank you very much. you were correct I had pasted the incorrect data into the correction string.  Thanks again, John.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Just another method that I have used for some time. It's pretty fast (could be faster). I pull a huge xml db from a gaming company every night. This is how i get it an import it.

```
 $xml  = new XMLReader();            
 $xml->open($xml_file); // file is your xml file you want to parse
 while($xml->read() && $xml->name != 'game') { ; } // get past the header to your first record (game in my case)

while($xml->name == 'game') { // now while we are in this record               
                $element        = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());
                $gameRec        = $this->createGameRecord($element, $os); // this is my function to reduce some clutter - and I use it elsewhere too

                /* this looks confusing, but it is not. There are over 20 fields, and instead of typing them all out, I just made a string. */
                $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (";
                foreach($gameRec as $field=>$game){
                $sql .= " $field,";
                }
                $sql = rtrim($sql, ",");
                $sql .=") values (";

                foreach($gameRec as $field=>$game) {
                    $sql .= " :$field,";               
                }
                $sql = rtrim($sql,",");
                $sql .= ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "; // online game doesn't have a gamerank - not my choice LOL, so I adjust that for here

                switch ($os) {
                    case 'pc' : $sql .= "gamerank = ".$gameRec['gamerank']        ; break;
                    case 'mac': $sql .= "gamerank = ".$gameRec['gamerank']        ; break;
                    case 'pl' : $sql .= "playercount = ".$gameRec['playercount']  ; break;
                    case 'og' :
                        $playercount = $this->getPlayerCount($gameRec['gameid']);
                        $sql .= "playercount = ".$playercount['playercount']  ;
                        break;

                }


                try {

                    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->execute($gameRec);

                } catch (PDOException $e) {// Kludge

                    echo 'os: '.$os.'<br/>table: '.$table.'<br/>XML LINK: '.$comprehensive_xml.'<br/>Current Record:<br/><pre>'.print_r($gameRec).'</pre><br/>'.
                    'SQL: '.$sql.'<br/>';
                    die('Line:33<br/>Function: pullBFG()<BR/>Cannot add game record <br/>'.$e->getMessage());

                }

                /// VERY VERY VERY IMPORTANT do not forget these 2 lines, or it will go into a endless loop - I know, I've done it. locks up your system after a bit hahaah
                $xml->next('game');
                unset($element);
            }// while there are games
```

This should get you started. Obviously, adjust the "game" to your xml records. Trim out the fat I have here.

Here is the createGameRecord($element, $type='pc')
Basically it turns it into an array to use elsewhere, and makes it easier to add it to the db. with a single line as seen above: $stmt->execute($gameRec); Where $gameRec was returned from this function. PDO knows gameRec is an array, and will parse it out as you INSERT IT. the "delHardReturns() is another of my fucntion that gets rid of those hard returns /r /n etc.. Seems to mess up the SQL. I think SQL has a function for that, but I have not pursed it.
Hope you find this useful.

```
private function createGameRecord($element, $type='pc') {
            if( ($type == 'pc') || ($type == 'og') ) { // player count is handled separately
                $game = array(
                    'gamename'                  => strval($element->gamename),
                    'gameid'                    => strval($element->gameid),                
                    'genreid'                   => strval($element->genreid),
                    'allgenreid'                => strval($element->allgenreid),
                    'shortdesc'                 => $this->delHardReturns(strval($element->shortdesc)),
                    'meddesc'                   => $this->delHardReturns(strval($element->meddesc)),
                    'bullet1'                   => $this->delHardReturns(strval($element->bullet1)),
                    'bullet2'                   => $this->delHardReturns(strval($element->bullet2)),
                    'bullet3'                   => $this->delHardReturns(strval($element->bullet3)),
                    'bullet4'                   => $this->delHardReturns(strval($element->bullet4)),
                    'bullet5'                   => $this->delHardReturns(strval($element->bullet5)),
                    'longdesc'                  => $this->delHardReturns(strval($element->longdesc)),
                    'foldername'                => strval($element->foldername),
                    'hasdownload'               => strval($element->hasdownload),
                    'hasdwfeature'              => strval($element->hasdwfeature),                             
                    'releasedate'               => strval($element->releasedate)

                );

                if($type === 'pc')  {

                    $game['hasvideo']           = strval($element->hasvideo);
                    $game['hasflash']           = strval($element->hasflash);
                    $game['price']              = strval($element->price); 
                    $game['gamerank']           = strval($element->gamerank);
                    $game['gamesize']           = strval($element->gamesize);
                    $game['macgameid']          = strval($element->macgameid);
                    $game['family']             = strval($element->family);
                    $game['familyid']           = strval($element->familyid);
                    $game['productid']          = strval($element->productid);
                    $game['pc_sysreqos']        = strval($element->systemreq->pc->sysreqos);
                    $game['pc_sysreqmhz']       = strval($element->systemreq->pc->sysreqmhz);
                    $game['pc_sysreqmem']       = strval($element->systemreq->pc->sysreqmem);
                    $game['pc_sysreqhd']        = strval($element->systemreq->pc->sysreqhd);

                    if(empty($game['gamerank'])) $game['gamerank'] = 99999;

                    $game['gamesize'] = $this->readableBytes((int)$game['gamesize']);  


                }// dealing with PC type

                if($type === 'og') {
                    $game['onlineiframeheight']              = strval($element->onlineiframeheight);
                    $game['onlineiframewidth']              = strval($element->onlineiframewidth); 

                }

                $game['releasedate']            = substr($game['releasedate'],0,10);

            } else {// not type = pl

                $game['playercount']            = strval($element->playercount);
                $game['gameid']                 = strval($element->gameid);
            }// no type = pl else


            return $game;
        }/
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Much faster. I did some research, and while the above post I made shows one (slow) method, I was able to find one that works even faster - for me it does.
I put this as a new answer due to the complete difference from my previous post.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'path/to/file.xml' INTO TABLE tablename ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<xml-identifier>'
```

Example

```
<students>
    <student>
       <name>john doe</name>
          <boringfields>bla bla bla......</boringfields>
    </student>
</students>
```

Then, MYSQL command would be:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'path/to/students.xml' INTO TABLE tablename ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<student>'
```

rows identified must have single quote and angle brackets.
when I switched to this method, I went from 12min +/- to 30 seconds!! +/-

tips that worked for me. was use the
DELETE FROM tablename
otherwise it will just append to your db.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html