# 00E1 vs. A0 when using Bulk Insert to SQL Server vs. simple read line and insert it

Tags: sql-server, insert, bulk

I have a bunch of data (27M rows) in a flat file that I need to get into SQL Server. I have tried using Bulk Insert in SSMS, but when I do I get a bunch of records that contain only the character hex 00E1. Otoh, if I do a StreamReader ReadLine from the flat file and an Insert into the database I get a bunch of records that contain only the character A0. I don't know which is right (if either), and I know nothing about file encoding. The Bulk Insert statement looks like this:

```
Bulk Insert Barry
From 'C:\Temp\Job.txt'
With (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

Ideally, I'd like to understand what's going on and import the data properly. Absent that, I'd like the Bulk Insert to work like the ReadLine does, i.e., insert the A0 instead of the 00E1. Can someone please explain what's going on and hopefully help me get a good import? Thanks.

Comment: 0x00E1 is the Unicode non-breaking space character. You might try adding `DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'` as described in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql.

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried that. I get the following warning: "Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified as widechar. DataFileType will be assumed to be char because the data file does not have a Unicode signature." It still imports the file, but there are still 00E1 records in it.

Comment: Ok. Well, apparently this question is a non-starter. Let's try it this way: Can anyone think of a way to *quickly* get 27M rows from a flat file into SQL Server without adding characters to the records? As it is (doing it with ReadLine()) I calculate it's going to take until Saturday evening before it's done. Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the actual file encoding, it will be trial-and-error using `BULK INSERT` and you might need to use a format file. But if you are getting the data you want using `StreamReader.ReadLine`, you could use `SqlBulkCopy` in your app code. That technique usually inserts millions of rows per minute depending on hardware. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679921/importing-large-xml-file-into-sql-2-5gb for a Powershell example.