# Importing XML into SQL Server but trying to make multiple entries if multiple results exist for a child element

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, sql-server-2012

I have the following XML file that I import regularly into my SQL Server table `files_index`.

Here is a small sample of XML below, my table layout and the Powershell code I use to insert the data.

I use a PowerShell script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43680099/4420967)

The reason I am using PowerShell is that the file is 3.5gb so too big to use bulkinsert

This solution works perfectly and has been for a while however I use the XML element `Prod_ID` when in the table the column `Prod_ID` to join my data with files supplied by suppliers, in most cases this is fine but if you look at the XML, under the file node there is a lower one called `M_Prod_ID` this contains variations of the `Prod_ID` (used by different suppliers / countries) but it refers to the product in question.

To the question at last, can anyone suggest a way of if there is an entry or entries in the M_Prod_ID child of file how to create multiple entries for the file and all of its columns into my table. as when I join the Prod_ID with other tables I have not all matches are returned as certain products have multiple SKU's and I am only collecting the one in Prod_ID under the file node.

I hope I have explained this properly if there are any suggestions on how I can get these multiple results or any other way of joining the data (I did think to create a new table and for every Prod_ID value and every M_Prod_ID value and use them to do a join) but again I'm not really sure of the best solution. please can I have any suggestions, and thank you for reading this epic post.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ICECAT-interface SYSTEM "http://data.icecat.biz/dtd/files.index.dtd">
<!-- source: Icecat.biz 2019 -->
<ICECAT-interface xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://data.icecat.biz/xsd/files.index.xsd">
   <files.index Generated="20190309013133">
      <file path="export/level4/EN/1980.xml" Product_ID="1980" Updated="20190308212809" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="1" Prod_ID="CHP310" Catid="714" On_Market="1" Model_Name="CHP310" Product_View="212121" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/img_1980_high_1493356129_7496_32689.jpg" HighPicSize="2758330" HighPicWidth="4134" HighPicHeight="5433" Date_Added="20051004000000" Limited="No">
         <M_Prod_ID>CHP310?5PK</M_Prod_ID>
         <M_Prod_ID>CHP310/61623</M_Prod_ID>
         <M_Prod_ID>CHP310/BUN</M_Prod_ID>
         <EAN_UPCS>
            <EAN_UPC Value="5705965480120" IsApproved="0" />
            <EAN_UPC Value="4250786102412" IsApproved="0" />
         </EAN_UPCS>
         <Country_Markets>
            <Country_Market Value="GB" />
            <Country_Market Value="PL" />
         </Country_Markets>
      </file>
      <file path="export/level4/EN/2205.xml" Product_ID="2205" Updated="20190308073831" Quality="SUPPLIER" Supplier_id="1" Prod_ID="C6487C" Catid="234" On_Market="1" Model_Name="C6487C" Product_View="71542" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/gallery/2205_7952931385.jpg" HighPicSize="88121" HighPicWidth="573" HighPicHeight="430" Date_Added="20050627000000" Limited="No">
         <M_Prod_ID>C6487C#ABP</M_Prod_ID>
         <EAN_UPCS>
            <EAN_UPC Value="0808736280969" IsApproved="1" />
            <EAN_UPC Value="0808736340168" IsApproved="1" />
         </EAN_UPCS>
         <Country_Markets>
            <Country_Market Value="DE" />
            <Country_Market Value="AU" />
            <Country_Market Value="CH" />
            <Country_Market Value="ZA" />
         </Country_Markets>
      </file>
   </files.index>
</ICECAT-interface>
```

Table layout in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[files_index]
(
    [Product_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [path] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Updated] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Quality] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Supplier_id] [int] NULL,
    [Prod_ID] [varchar](MAX) NULL,
    [Catid] [int] NULL,
    [On_Market] [int] NULL,
    [Model_Name] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Product_View] [int] NULL,
    [HighPic] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [HighPicSize] [int] NULL,
    [HighPicWidth] [int] NULL,
    [HighPicHeight] [int] NULL,
    [Date_Added] [varchar](150) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Powershell Script

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -scope Currentuser

[String]$global:connectionString = "Data Source=Apps2\Apps2;Initial 
Catalog=ICECAT;Integrated Security=SSPI";
[System.Data.DataTable]$global:dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
[System.Xml.XmlTextReader]$global:xmlReader = New-Object 
System.Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\Scripts\icecat\files.index.xml");
[Int32]$global:batchSize = 50000;

Function Add-FileRow() {
    $newRow = $dt.NewRow();
    $null = $dt.Rows.Add($newRow);
    $newRow["Product_ID"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_ID");
    $newRow["path"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("path");
    $newRow["Updated"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Updated");
    $newRow["Quality"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Quality");
    $newRow["Supplier_id"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Supplier_id");
    $newRow["Prod_ID"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Prod_ID");
    $newRow["Catid"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Catid");
    $newRow["On_Market"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("On_Market");
    $newRow["Model_Name"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Model_Name");
    $newRow["Product_View"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_View");
    $newRow["HighPic"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPic");
    $newRow["HighPicSize"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicSize");
    $newRow["HighPicWidth"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicWidth");
    $newRow["HighPicHeight"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicHeight");
    $newRow["Date_Added"] = $global:xmlReader.GetAttribute("Date_Added");
}


     # init data table schema
    $da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM files_index WHERE 0 = 1", $global:connectionString);
    $null = $da.Fill($global:dt);
    $bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($global:connectionString);
    $bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.files_index";

    $recordCount = 0;



    while($xmlReader.Read() -eq $true)
    {

        if(($xmlReader.NodeType -eq [System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element) -and 
($xmlReader.Name -eq "file"))
         {
            Add-FileRow -xmlReader $xmlReader;
            $recordCount += 1;
            if(($recordCount % $global:batchSize) -eq 0) 
            {
                $bcp.WriteToServer($dt);
                $dt.Rows.Clear();
                Write-Host "$recordCount file elements processed so far";
            }
        }

    }

     if($dt.Rows.Count -gt 0)
     {
         $bcp.WriteToServer($dt);
     }

    $bcp.Close();
    $xmlReader.Close();



    Write-Host "$recordCount file elements imported ";


catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating your data in the SQL database, I strongly recommend introducing a new table that contains two columns, `ProdId` and `VariantProdId`. Add any `M_Prod_ID` there. After that it's easy to write an INNER JOIN that gets the right details for any kind of Product ID. This saves space in the database, it prevents data anomalies and it is much easier to support in your import script.

Comment: I have been thinking and yes that seems the best approach, however I have been struggling with my powershell script to get the Prod_ID from the file node and the multiple values if they exist from the child node M_Prod_ID. I can run a separate script after to return the values needed and then insert the data into a new table. Can you suggest how to go about this as I can pull in the Prod_ID from the file node but can't seem to extract the Values from M_Prod_ID it just returns null's

Comment: First step, make that table and a Powershell function that can insert values there. Insert a few values manually and write the SQL to select an item by one of its alternative IDs. If everything works out, change the import loop: The `XmlReader` visits every node in your input, in document order, like moving a cursor through a text letter-by-letter. When it currently stands on a `<file>` element, you can access that element's attributes (as done in `Add-FileRow`). Write a new `elseif` section that calls your new function when the reader stands on `<M_Prod_ID>` elements.

Comment: Hint: Always also insert the primary product ID into the "alternatives" table. This way you can use the same INNER JOIN query, no matter whether you are searching for an alternative ID or the primary one (i.e. you could make a VIEW).

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, I have set up my sql new table and can input new data 2 columns Product_ID and M_Produ_ID and have put both the original Prod_ID and M_Prod_ID data

Comment: and like you said created a view to retrieve the data required, all works fine but I am really stuck on the p shell code which is using XMLreader which I found .net I have found since, are you interested in a price to get this going for me as as much as I want to learn this its a bit above my skill range (I am a lot better at SQL, even that I am learning daily but I have more experience.) than the programming side.  How ever much I try I cant seem to return any data from the M_Prod_ID child elements, It puts the right amount of lines in but there is no data and I dont have anyone local to ask

Comment: I understand exactly what I need to do and you explained it very well, but knowing what i need to do and doing it is a different matter. I will keep plugging away today but let me know please.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but I'm not here for the money. I'm doing this for free (or not at all).

Comment: Ok no worries I appreciate that, I may be onto something so Ill be back shortly. thanks  John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty far. It's completely untested, so please read the code, understand it, and make the appropriate changes to get it to work.

I've removed the `function` and inlined all the code into the loop instead, the function was too bulky for my taste. Now you should be able to see more clearly what's going on.

Effectively it's the exact same code two times, with a small extra step that adds self-references so you can query every product via its primary ID and and its secondary IDs in the same way, as discussed in the comments.

```
$connectionString = "Data Source=Apps2\Apps2;Initial Catalog=ICECAT;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$batchSize = 50000

# set up [files_index] datatable & read schema from DB
$files_index_table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$files_index_adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM files_index WHERE 0 = 1", $connectionString)
$files_index_adapter.Fill($files_index_table) | Out-Null
$files_index_bcp = New-Object SqlBulkCopy($connectionString)
$files_index_bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.files_index"
$files_index_count = 0

# set up [product_ids] datatable & read schema from DB
$product_ids_table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$product_ids_adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM product_ids WHERE 0 = 1", $connectionString)
$product_ids_adapter.Fill($product_ids_table) | Out-Null
$product_ids_bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionString)
$product_ids_bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.product_ids"
$product_ids_count = 0

# main import loop
$xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\Scripts\icecat\files.index.xml")
while ($xmlReader.Read()) {
    # skip any XML nodes that aren't elements
    if ($xmlReader.NodeType -ne [System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element) { continue }

    # handle <file> elements
    if ($xmlReader.Name -eq "file") {
        $files_index_count++

        # remember current product ID, we'll need it when we hit the next <M_Prod_ID> element
        $curr_product_id = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_ID")
        $is_new_file = $true

        $newRow = $files_index_table.NewRow()
        $newRow["Product_ID"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_ID")
        $newRow["path"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("path")
        $newRow["Updated"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Updated")
        $newRow["Quality"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Quality")
        $newRow["Supplier_id"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Supplier_id")
        $newRow["Prod_ID"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Prod_ID")
        $newRow["Catid"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Catid")
        $newRow["On_Market"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("On_Market")
        $newRow["Model_Name"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Model_Name")
        $newRow["Product_View"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_View")
        $newRow["HighPic"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPic")
        $newRow["HighPicSize"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicSize")
        $newRow["HighPicWifiles_index_tableh"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicWifiles_index_tableh")
        $newRow["HighPicHeight"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicHeight")
        $newRow["Date_Added"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Date_Added")
        $files_index_table.Rows.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

        if ($files_index_table.Rows.Count -eq $batchSize) {
            $files_index_bcp.WriteToServer($files_index_table)
            $files_index_table.Rows.Clear()
            Write-Host "$files_index_count <file> elements processed so far"
        }
    # handle <M_Prod_ID> elements
    } elseif ($xmlReader.Name -eq "M_Prod_ID") {
        $product_ids_count++

        # add self-reference row to the [product_ids] table
        # only for the first <M_Prod_ID> per <file> we need to do this
        if ($is_new_file) {
            $newRow = $product_ids_table.NewRow()
            $newRow["Product_ID"] = $curr_product_id  # from above
            $newRow["Alternative_ID"] = $curr_product_id
            $product_ids_table.Rows.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
            $is_new_file = $false
        }

        $newRow = $product_ids_table.NewRow()
        $newRow["Product_ID"] = $curr_product_id  # from above
        $newRow["Alternative_ID"] = $xmlReader.Value
        $product_ids_table.Rows.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

        if ($product_ids_table.Rows.Count -eq $batchSize) {
            $product_ids_bcp.WriteToServer($files_index_table)
            $product_ids_table.Rows.Clear()
            Write-Host "$product_ids_count <M_Prod_ID> elements processed so far"
        }
    }
}

# write any remaining rows to the server
if ($files_index_table.Rows.Count -gt 0) {
    $files_index_bcp.WriteToServer($files_index_table)
    $files_index_table.Rows.Clear()
}
Write-Host "$files_index_count <file> elements processed overall"

if ($product_ids_table.Rows.Count -gt 0) {
    $product_ids_bcp.WriteToServer($product_ids_table)
    $product_ids_table.Rows.Clear()
}
Write-Host "$product_ids_count <M_Prod_ID> elements processed overall"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will post up the changes I had to make to get it going, but its running now and as the file is so big its going to take a while.(I should have ran it on a smaller file) @Tomalak ill keep you updated.

Comment: not quite there yet but am so much further thanks, ill be posting it all when it works perfectly.

Comment: using your code I am so close, I have changed it a bit and have leared a lot thank you.  how can I post my code as I have 1 small question and would like to show you what I have changed. am I allowed to answer my own question on here or do I create a new thread ?

Comment: I did it, thanks again, one little line was stopping the M_Prod_ID values from being returned. thank you very much @Tomalak Ill post the code if you let me know how. your help was invaluable.

Comment: That's some great news, good to hear you figured it out! You could post your own answer if you want to.

Comment: I have been going through the data and cause there are over 6 million rows in the file node it takes a while but I did some tests and the script currently works perfectly if there are 50000 or less rows but after that it seems to repeat some data. It writes 50000 rows at a time to the files_index table but doesn't write the product_id's table data until the end. and I have found some duplicates in the data that should not be there as they are not in the xml file.

Comment: I have jacked up the memory on my server and got rid of some unnecessary columns that I can collect again at a later date and insert and am currently running the script to pull in the whole file at once and process. we shall see. not ideal but if it works I can go back later and mess with the script.

Comment: Jacking up the memory should not be necessary. Try reducing the batch size.

Comment: I went though the file with the massive batch size no errors but!! I retrieved back less Product_ID's rows in the  product_ids table than I did in the files_index table so its defiantly skipping something, what I dont quite get  is that it writes out the data to the files_index table in batches of however many batches I make the $batchSize variable to be, but doesnt write any data to the product_ids table until after the job has run ie (it inserts all data to the product_ids table at the very end rather than as and when it parses each batch) and I cant trust the data.

Answer (score 0):

@Tomalak I managed to change your code and get it working, thanks very much for the help I couldn't have done it without your help and really appreciate you help and guidance, the code could probably be cleaned up a bit but I cant find any flaws in the data after a couple of days of testing. I ran it on a 3.6GB file which produced around 6.5 million rows in the files_index table and 7.4 million rows in the product_ids table, so I have now nearly a million potential skus that I can potentially match data on.

I changed it so it also added a row to the product_ids table even if there isnt a child node of M_Prod_ID with the Product ID and Prod_ID, this way it was easier to make a view to match the data.  CODE BELOW.......

```
> Blockquote$connectionString = "Data Source=Apps2\Apps2;Initial 
 Catalog=ICECATtesting;Integrated Security=SSPI"
$batchSize = 100000

 # set up [files_index] datatable & read schema from DB
$files_index_table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
$files_index_adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM 
files_index WHERE 0 = 1", $connectionString)
$files_index_adapter.Fill($files_index_table) | Out-Null;
$files_index_bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionString)  
$files_index_bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.files_index"
$files_index_count = 0;

# set up [product_ids] datatable & read schema from DB
$product_ids_table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$product_ids_adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM 
product_ids WHERE 0 = 1", $connectionString)
$product_ids_adapter.Fill($product_ids_table) | Out-Null
$product_ids_bcp = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionString)
$product_ids_bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.product_ids"
$product_ids_count = 0

 # main import loop

$xmlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\Scripts\icecat\files.index.xml")
while ($xmlReader.Read()) {
# skip any XML nodes that aren't elements
if ($xmlReader.NodeType -ne [System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element) { continue }

# handle <file> elements
if ($xmlReader.Name -eq "file") {
    $files_index_count++

    # remember current product ID, we'll need it when we hit the next <M_Prod_ID> 
  element also add the Prod_ID from the file node
    $curr_product_id = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_ID")
    $curr_prod_id = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Prod_ID")
    $is_new_file = $false

    $newRow = $files_index_table.NewRow()
    $newRow["Product_ID"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_ID")
    $newRow["path"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("path")
    $newRow["Updated"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Updated")
    $newRow["Quality"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Quality")
    $newRow["Supplier_id"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Supplier_id")
    $newRow["Prod_ID"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Prod_ID")
    $newRow["Catid"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Catid")
    $newRow["On_Market"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("On_Market")
    $newRow["Model_Name"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Model_Name")
    $newRow["Product_View"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Product_View")
    $newRow["HighPic"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPic")
    $newRow["HighPicSize"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicSize")
    $newRow["HighPicWidth"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicWidth")
    $newRow["HighPicHeight"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("HighPicHeight")
    $newRow["Date_Added"] = $xmlReader.GetAttribute("Date_Added")
    $Firstproduct_id = $xmlreader.GetAttribute("Product_ID")
    $Firstprod_id = $xmlreader.GetAttribute("Prod_ID")
    $newfilenode = $true

    $files_index_table.Rows.Add($newRow) | Out-Null
    $newRow = $product_ids_table.NewRow()
    $newRow["Product_ID"] = $curr_product_id  # from above
    $newRow["Alternative_ID"] = $curr_prod_id
    $product_ids_table.Rows.Add($newRow) | Out-Null


    if ($files_index_table.Rows.Count -eq $batchSize) {
        $files_index_bcp.WriteToServer($files_index_table)
        $files_index_table.Rows.Clear()
        Write-Host "$files_index_count <file> elements processed so far"

    }
    # handle <M_Prod_ID> elements
    } elseif ($xmlReader.Name -eq "M_Prod_ID") {
         $product_ids_count++

         # add self-reference row to the [product_ids] table also I added the Prod_ID 
from the file node so I can make a view to match all variants

    # only for the first <M_Prod_ID> per <file> we need to do this


        $xmlreader.read()
        $newRow = $product_ids_table.NewRow()
        $newRow["Product_ID"] = $curr_product_id  # from above
        $newRow["Alternative_ID"] = $xmlReader.Value
        $product_ids_table.Rows.Add($newRow) | Out-Null


    if ($product_ids_table.Rows.Count -eq $batchSize) {
        $product_ids_bcp.WriteToServer($product_ids_table)
        $product_ids_table.Rows.Clear()
        Write-Host "$product_ids_count <M_Prod_ID> elements processed so far"
    }
  }
 }

 # write any remaining rows to the server
if ($files_index_table.Rows.Count -gt 0) {
$files_index_bcp.WriteToServer($files_index_table)
$files_index_table.Rows.Clear()
}
Write-Host "$files_index_count <file> elements processed overall"

if ($product_ids_table.Rows.Count -gt 0) {
    $product_ids_bcp.WriteToServer($product_ids_table)
    $product_ids_table.Rows.Clear()
 }
 Write-Host "$product_ids_count <M_Prod_ID> elements processed overall"
```