# Speeding up Import of XML into SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, parallel-processing, bulkinsert

Hi I have a working Powershell script to import a large XML file I work with regularly into my SQL server.

The file is too large to import directly (4.5Gb) so the Powershell script user @Tomalak helped me lots with is currently working fine but it still takes 2 plus hours to run.  I am trying to find a faster option.

[Link to previous post on generating the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55083962/importing-xml-into-sql-server-but-trying-to-make-multiple-entries-if-multiple-re)

I am trying to speed up the process and was thinking recently of splitting the XML into smaller files and  looping through using SQL's Bulk insert also perhaps Splitting the file and using Powershell but running it in parallel.

Will Bulk insert run faster than powershell at inserting the data ? Also I don't think its the inserts that are taking the time more the looping through and extracting the data from the XML file its self.

Can anyone point me in a different direction or suggest a way that would deal with this task faster?

Open to all options.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Will Bulk insert run faster than powershell at inserting the data ?" - you're in a better position than anyone to answer that question :) try it and measure the difference

Comment: I will give that a go, I only just managed to get the file split in the last hour and was more asking if I am thinking along the right lines. I have googled lots but thought id ask as there are so many ways to do any task,

Comment: I'd say it's definitely a worthwhile experiment - I've had luck with speeding up similar imports from flat files by generating huge INSERT statements and submitting those instead of programmatically try to import row-by-row.

Comment: I am currently writing a bulk insert script so will defiantly give it a go and report back.

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from performing some optimization on the XML before doing an import. XML files are by their very nature bloated. Reducing the length of tag names can have a dramatic impact on file size (and thus parsing performance). Changing "ProductID" to just "P" for instance. It doesn't even have to be every tag in the file, just the more common ones. I've been able to reduce XML file sizes from anywhere between 50-80%. Of course you'll have to change your import to read in new field names.

You can experiment by pulling a portion of your XML into an editor and globally search/replace tag names to see how it effects file size.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a go to speed thiings up even further, I ended up splitting the files and importing them using buk insert and used openrowset to return the data

Comment: Ill update my post above with the details.  shaved 2hrs roughly off of my job. just running some tests and recording the numbers the new way vs poweshell on the large file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so using @Matthius R. jessen's suggestion I split my main file into chunks of 500000

Split the file using this software [Firstobject XMl editor(free)](http://www.firstobject.com/xml-splitter-script-video.htm) can call from the command line and was able to load a very large xml file where other bits of software struggled.

I then used this to pull the data from the split file.

```
USE [OPENXMLTesting]
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[XMLwithOpenXML]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XMLwithOpenXML](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [XMLData] [xml] NULL,
    [LoadedDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

USE OPENXMLTesting
GO

INSERT INTO XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Scripts\ImportTest\piece1.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM XMLwithOpenXML
```

Total time **34 seconds** to insert the data to SQL

then queried the results for the main data I wanted from the  element using

```
USE OPENXMLTesting
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT Product_ID, path, Updated, Quality, Supplier_id, Prod_ID, Catid, On_Market, 
Model_Name, Product_View, HighPic, HighPicSize, HighPicWidth, HighPicHeight, 
Date_Added
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'root/file')
WITH 
(
`Product_ID [int] '@Product_ID',
path [varchar](100) '@path',
Updated [varchar](50) '@Updated',
Quality [varchar](50) '@Quality',
Supplier_id [int] '@Supplier_id',
Prod_ID [varchar] '@Prod_ID',
Catid [int] '@Catid',
On_Market [int] '@On_Market',
Model_Name [varchar](250) '@Model_Name',
Product_View [int] '@Product_View',
HighPic [varchar] '@HighPic',
HighPicSize [int] '@HighPicSize',
HighPicWidth [int] '@HighPicWidth',
HighPicHeight [int] '@HighPicHeight',
Date_Added [varchar](150) '@Date_Added'
)


EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Total time for this step **57 seconds** to retrieve the child element of root  and its attributes

Then as I needed to bring back the child of the  element  and also the referring Prod_ID from the parent  element so I can later perform a join on the data.

I ran

```
USE OPENXMLTesting
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT Prod_ID, M_Prod_ID
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'root/file/M_Prod_ID',2)
WITH 
(
Prod_ID [varchar] (50) '../@Prod_ID',
M_Prod_ID [varchar] (50) '../M_Prod_ID'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Total **32 Seconds**.

So total time to pull in and query 500,000 lines of the Element I wanted and the Child of that took **2 mins 3 seconds**. not an actual insert but a select so maybe a little more to get the data into the db but not much.

I then tried the same using my old Powershell script and it took **6 Mins 39 Seconds**.

if working on the whole file this will now take roughly 32 mins compared to around 2.5 hrs, so a large improvement.  All I need to do now is write a script to loop through the split files and import one after the other.

Thanks for the suggestions all.  I am happy with the results.  I can probably speed it up a little more by cleaning the XML further before but for now I am very happy with what will now be a much shorter process.

Comment: Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is better to use **XQuery** language, based on the w3c standards, to deal with the XML data type.
Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument`  and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with obsolete SQL Server 2000.
It is strongly recommended to re-write you SQL and switch it to XQuery. You can ask a separate question on the subject.

Comment: OK thank you for your input, I was just going off of a tutorial I found online.  Looks like I have some new tools to learn.  I will make the changes and update the post.  Any recommended tutorials or guides ?

Comment: Your post has 2 questions: (1) how to import an XML file into SQL Server. (2) how to query XML data type column in SQL Server. It is better to split your post into 2 questions.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and link. Is the way I have imported the data the preferred way? or would you suggest a different approach?

Comment: Your import part is ok.